# Take input from variable and output to file in bash

Tags: c++, bash, io

I have an exe file complied via `g++` and it takes a number as input and gives a few numbers as output.
Now, I need to write a bash script to loop it from 1 to 10 and get the outputs in 10 separate files.

I know how to take input from a file and give corresponding output to file:

```
./a.exe <in.txr >out.txt
```

but, I need something like:

```
for (( iter=1; iter<=5; iter++ ))
do
   ./a.exe (take input as $iter) >$iter.txt;
done
```

How do I do that? I read about the `read` command. Where do I put it.

PS: I'm a newbie to bash scripting.

Comment: Does `a.exe` expect a command-line argument, or will it read from standard input? The two are not the same.

Comment: Basically my cpp file had a `scanf` in it. What input would that be?

Comment: That sounds like standard input, but if you have the choice, you should modify the program to take a single command line argument instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Herestring

```
for (( iter=1; iter=<10; iter++ ))
do
  ./a.exe <<< $iter > $iter.txt
done
```